# Making a table by using data which getting together 4 different list

Tags: python, dataframe, join, datatable

I try to make a table by getting together four list.
My code as below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver_path= "C:\\Users\\Bacanli\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe"
browser=webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
browser.get("http://www.bddk.org.tr/BultenHaftalik")
time.sleep(3)


Krediler=browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='tabloListesiItem-253']/span")
Krediler.click()


elements = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("td.ortala:nth-child(2)")
TPs=browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("td[data-label='TP']")
YPs=browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("td[data-label='YP']")
Toplams=browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("td[data-label='Toplam']")
```

My intend is that make a new table by getting together elements, TPs, YPs, Toplams.
Thanks for your helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Pandas` makes this easy for you:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html('http://www.bddk.org.tr/BultenHaftalik')
```

will create a list of pandas dataframes from html tables on the page. The table you want is `df[3]`.

Result `df[3].head()`:

|  | Unnamed: 0 | Sektör / Krediler ( 9 Temmuz 2021 Cuma ) (Milyon TL) | TP | YP | TOPLAM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | Toplam Krediler (2+10) | 2.479.94928 | 1.427.80395 | 3.907.75323 |
| 1 | 2 | Tüketici Kredileri ve Bireysel Kredi Kartları (3+7) | 877.62363 | 30181 | 877.92544 |
| 2 | 3 | Tüketici Kredileri (4+5+6) | 710.18775 | 11070 | 710.29845 |
| 3 | 4 | a) Konut | 278.38213 | 7473 | 278.45686 |
| 4 | 5 | b) Taşıt | 14.91958 | 000 | 14.91958 |

export to csv with `df[3].to_csv('filename.csv')`

(or you could use the export to excel button above the table on the website)

Comment: RJ Adriaansen thks for helping. But the problem is that after using selenium I can not the codes you suggested. Those work separately.